# Plot the color and line type in the same legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying plot a set of lines, some lines I want to have dashed-lines and for some I want to have different colors. And each line will have a combination of linetype and color.

However when I set `linetype` and `color` in ggplot2 I get two legends printed.

How can I get one set of legend where each entry in the legend contains the information on the line type and color?

For example for the below I would expect 4 entries in the legend, one for each of red solid lines, red dashed-lines, blue solid lines, and blue dashed-lines.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = disp, x = mpg, color = as.factor(vs),
                linetype = as.factor(am)))
```

**Example of the output that I *DON'T* want; just want one legend box**
[image: I want one legend instead of two]

Comment: Perhaps `interaction(vs, am)` for color and linetype?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a new variable based on the interaction of `vs` and `am`. This gives 4 values: (0, 0), (1, 0), (0,1) and (1, 1). You can then specify color manually. And a line graph is inappropriate for the data here; use points.

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs_am = interaction(vs, am)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = vs_am, shape = vs_am)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "red", "blue"))
```

[image]

If you really want lines, I would use `geom_smooth` to add a "best fit" line using linear regression for each group:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(vs_am = interaction(vs, am)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color = vs_am, shape = vs_am)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "red", "blue")) + 
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", aes(group = vs_am, color = vs_am))
```

[image]